# Unable to remove item from List ?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-sortable

I'm trying to remove single item from list after re-ordering but it seem to remove multiple items from list on single click .

**Code:**

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ["kendo.directives"]);
testApp.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.mapList = [];
  $scope.addMap = function() {
    $scope.mapList.push({
      'mapNameList': [{
        'mapName': 'Test1'
      }]
    });
  };

  $scope.placeholder = function(element) {
    return element.clone().addClass("placeholder").text("drop here");
  };

  $scope.hint = function(element) {
    return element.clone().addClass("hint"); >>---- i feel issue is because of this part but not sure 
  };

  $scope.removeItem = function(data, index) {
    data.mapNameList.splice(index, 1); // it removes multiple but fires one time .
  };

  $scope.addMap = function() {
    $scope.mapList.push({
      'mapNameList': [{
        'mapName': 'Test1'
      }]
    });
  };

  $scope.addDetail = function(data) {
    data.mapNameList.push({
      'mapName': "Test"
    });
  };

}]);
```

Sample working fiddle **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/3s1ghdp3/)**

**Steps to Reproduce :** *//refer fiddle link*

1.)click on Add Map .

2.)Now click on Add Detail for 5 times .

3.)now try reordering the records by drag and drop up & down .

4.)Click on any delete button .

- It will remove **multiple records** when delete button is clicked & delete further stops working .

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look at the `kendo-sortable` directive, it seems like there's an issue with inheritance and the `$index` variable. I don't want to sound like I know for sure what's going on since I haven't looked at the directive much, but dragging the element does not change its position (index) in the array, but the removeItem function is being called using `$index` and it somehow is targeting the wrong item.

Either way, I was able to fix the bug by changing line 26 on the HTML from:

`<li ng-repeat="n in data.mapNameList">`

to:

`<li ng-repeat="n in data.mapNameList track by $index">`

I think part of the issue might be because there are duplicates. The array is a list of objects though, so Angular can't track them by comparison unless you give Angular something to track them by. I think. So, deleting them when out of order can mess with how Angular is tracking them. Giving Angular something to track solves this.

Comment: Did not work for me. Add 3 details, place the last one first, then delete him. Still deletes more than one.

Comment: Huh, strange. I tested it the same way except using less than three objects. It seems to only break when something is reordered to the beginning more than one index. I'll take another look

Comment: so weird it might be bug or something to do with kendo sortable @tpsilva